# GPO: allow hardware configuration (VLAN)

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I have created an AD group and added it to the group of network operators so that the members of the group have permission to change IP addresses, etc.

However, for some cases, there is a situation where a USB Ethernet adapter is needed is to be set up on a VLAN .. Unfortunately, as a "non-admin" Member the configuration of the adapter (ie the tab under configuration) is not visible, so the members of the group can not configure a VLAN.

Can someone tell me how to enable this with GPO policies?

I'm looking for this for a while now but I can not find anything suitable..

EDIT:

I guess I've found the right GPO under: User Configuration | Administrative Templates | Network | Network Connections
--> "Prohibit Access to the Advanced Settings Item on the Advanced Menu"

BUT: It says, that the users needs to be a Administrator to view the Advanced Menu... is there a workaround? I don't want the users to be within the Administrator Group

Comment: You need to provide a screen shot of the configuration page as both an Administrator and a member of Network Configuration Operators.

Comment: The marked tab ("Advanced" in english) is just missing for all users but the Admin: http://prntscr.com/kc4aft